# Foreach inside a While loop with joined tables

Tags: if-statement, foreach, while-loop

OK...not looking for code just yet.  I'm making a change on how I handle a list of colleges.

I had one column in my a_players table called Offers.  It was basically a CSV of Colleges that I exploded and sorted, but I would have to go in directly to the table to add to it.  I want more flexibility and detail, including timestamp (Date), so I created a Colleges table and for each scholarship offer, an Offers table.  All of this shows up on a Player's Profile.

Below is the query.  The problem I'm having is how to handle the data from Offers table. I do have a FOREACH loop set up, which is how I handled the exploded and sorted from the CSV.

```
$query = "SELECT *,p.id as pid,p.city,p.school FROM a_players p

            LEFT JOIN a_players_offers po   
                ON p.id = po.playerID
            LEFT JOIN a_colleges c
                ON po.collegeID = c.id
```

When I have a WHILE loop with the query results, if a kid has six offers, it prints all the profile information six times, including the College name.  When I have an IF loop, it only prints the Player Profile once, but it also just prints the first college.

I think if I get some direction, I can produce the code myself.  I just can't seem to find any samples when I have searched.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT is the pathway for this, if anyone else comes across this with the same problem.